# Adding the two integers but one declared as an "int" and other as "auto"?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I am trying to find the sum of all the elements in an array, and declaring my initial accumulator variable `sum` as `0` using `auto`.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    auto sum {0};
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> arr(n);
    for(int arr_i = 0;arr_i < n;arr_i++){
        cin >> arr[arr_i];
        sum=sum+arr[arr_i];
     }
     cout<<sum;
     return 0;
}
```

It is giving me a compilation error. I want to know what is wrong with this.

> error: no match for 'operator+' in 'sum + arr.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] >(((std::vector::size_type)arr_i))'|

I'm using code blocks with gcc compiler and yes C++ 11 is enabled.

Comment: In `auto sum{0}`, `sum` is an `std::initializer_list<int>` with one element, `0`.

Comment: [Not reproduced](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d03e269a9019949). Compile your code with C++11 enabled.

Comment: @TavianBarnes, no, it is not.

Comment: What compiler are you using? What compiler flags are you using? Please add them to the post. Also add the compiler error to the post.

Comment: *It is giving me a compilation error*. Well, what error? Can we see it?

Comment: and please add it to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: @SergeyA This was true until [N3922](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html).  I assume his compiler still implements the old rule.

Comment: @TavianBarnes, now it is a correct statement! :)

Comment: @SergeyA Honestly I was surprised that they retconned the C++11 standard for this, I assumed it was too late for that.  Or did the compilers just decide to do it in C++11 mode too for convenience?

Comment: @TavianBarnes, I believe it to be C++11 (though I do not have a copy in front of me). CLang actually has an interesting behaviour in versions 3.6 and 3.7 (in c++11 mode) - it errors, but says that behavior will be changed in next version. I find it cute.

Comment: @SergeyA Indeed.  They also explain that the C++11 and 14 modes were both changed [per the request of the C++ committee](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#n3922).

Comment: What version of gcc are you using? According to [this](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2015/09/thoughts-on-vagaries-of-c-initialization.html), gcc 5.1 implements N3922. If you're using an older version, then TavianBarnes' comment explains the reason for the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++11, when you use

```
auto sum {0};
```

then`sum` is of type `std::initializer_list<int>` and contains one element, `0`. This is because the `{0}` is a braced initialization list.

Using `= 0;` or `(0)` should work properly for your code, e.g:

```
auto sum = 0;
auto sum(0);
```

**EDIT:** According to the comments this was NOT what programmers [usually expected](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2015/09/thoughts-on-vagaries-of-c-initialization.html), hence it is bound to change in C++17 with the [N3922](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html) proposal, which is already implemented in newer versions of GCC and Clang, with even for `-std=c++11` and `-std=c++14` [per the request of the C++ committee](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#n3922).

Comment: It does you no good to repeat after @TavianBarnes - this user is mistaken.

Comment: @SergeyA I'm sorry I don't understand what you're saying?

Comment: Your answer appeared after comment from Tavian, and is very close to it in wording. However, both your answer and Tavian's initial comment are incorrect.

Comment: @SergeyA Yeah, I noticed that right after posting my answer, so I changed mine. I didn't plagiarize, chill. :-) You're welcome to post a correct answer.

Comment: since gcc 5.1.0 `auto sum{0}` is an int, so it appears OP is using old compiler

Comment: @MarcinJędrzejewski GCC 5 is too new on most systems. The latest stable GCC 4.9.3 on my Gentoo machine failed with the exact same error the OP later posted. Not everybody is using as bleeding-edge as compiler developers / C++ evangelists do.

Comment: @jotik with http://melpon.org/wandbox/ you can test all possible gcc versions with a single click. But I agree, at work I am stuck with gcc 4.9 and even VS2005,....

Comment: @SergeyA How are you so sure this answer is incorrect? Yes, N3922 is a DR that applies to C++11 and later, but the OP could be using an older gcc version that doesn't implement the DR.

Comment: @MarcinJędrzejewski Took me about 10 clicks to turn un-adblock all the javascript used by that site. Note that many people (including me and probably including the OP) have originally no idea such tools exists, and one shouldn't expect them to.

Comment: @Praetorian, without additional wording, the answer seems to be talking about current c++11 standard - and is incorrect as such. Be it a an answer with explanation why and how, I would upvote it instead of downvoting.

Comment: @SergeyA Agreed, the answer the could be improved a lot by mentioning the DR and the resulting change in behavior. It's not worthy of an upvote in its current state :)